# Modify system generated error messages batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

I am using a batch script to delete a scheduled task, if exists on the system already.

```
schtasks /query /TN TestTask  > C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\schtaskdel.log 2>&1
if %errorlevel%==0 (
SCHTASKS /delete /TN "TestTask " /F >C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\schtaskdel.log 2>&1
)
```

Now when the TestTask does not exist, I see an error in schtaskdel.log stating **ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified.**

Is there a way to modify this error message and add a custom message in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
>nul schtasks /query /TN TestTask  2>&1
if %errorlevel%==0 (
SCHTASKS /delete /TN "TestTask " /F >C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\schtaskdel.log 2>&1
) ELSE echo %Your message% >C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\schtaskdel.log
```